# How to use websockets in Visual Studio http files

Tags: visual-studio, web-api-testing, .http-files

I am looking to test websocket connections using Visual Studio 2022 http files. Could not find any documentation on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/http-files?view=aspnetcore-8.0.